# Match alpha characters and spaces between specific tags

Tags: regex, vbscript, replace, find

I would like this pattern to find ANY letters that happen to be between the  &  tags.
The amount of digits between the tags will be variable amounts (sometimes 5, sometimes 5-4, sometimes 9)  Basically we always want numbers between the tags.  Sometimes my text files may come to me with letters or spaces between the tags.

What I want my script to do is count the amount of times it finds letters [a-zA-Z) between the tags.  If it finds 0 then it will report 0.

My current test text file has 2 zipcode tags ... 
both of them only have numbers between the tags (this is GOOD)
the script or pattern below should show 0 found (since there are no letters)
However it reports back 2.  As if it is backwards.
IF I put a letter in one of the tags, this pattern below will report 1.
It is as if the pattern is backwards.  If I change it to [^0-9]* nothing is found no matter if there is letters or numbers or both.

```
Set rgxp3 = New Regexp
rgxp3.Pattern = "<ZipCode>([^a-zA-Z]*)</ZipCode>"
rgxp3.IgnoreCase = False
rgxp3.Global = True
Set matches3 = rgxp3.Execute( contents )
```

Comment: You say you want to match alphabetic characters, but your sample string has only digits and a hyphen. Also you're making your regexp case-sensitive when you have a case-mismatch between your pattern and the sample string. Please take a step back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve by applying this regular expression.

Comment: Ansgar I have updated what I currently have down for a pattern.  I want to only find uppercase or lowercase letters when they are between the zipcode tags. The script I am creating is making sure a format is correct.  The format can not have letters in between the tag.  So when I run this script I will want the search to come back as 0 occurrences of letters in between the tags.  If the script reports an occurrence then I know somewhere in my long text file, one of the many zipcodes tags has a letter in between them.  Numbers and hyphens are ok.  Thank you for being patient with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your last comment you want to find matches that have letters anywhere in the value of the tag, e.g. `<zipcode>123c456</zipcode>`. Try this:

```
str = "..."

Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "<zipcode>(.*?[a-z].*?)</zipcode>"
re.Global  = True
re.IgnoreCase = True

For Each m In re.Execute(str)
  WScript.Echo m.SubMatches(0)
Next
```

Comment: That is the right expression needed thank you.  Not sure if I should put this here, but I made the expression "<zipcode>(.*?[ a-zA-Z].*?)</zipcode>"   which will check for Upper & Lowercase & Spaces.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Usually in regex grouping is used to extract parts within a statement ([uses the brackets()].

So to solve this you would write a regex string such as;

```
<zipcode>([\da-zA-Z]{5}-[\da-zA-Z]{4})</zipcode>
```

(This regex string looks for 5 alphanumeric characters, followed by a hyphen (-), followed by 4 alphanumeric characters. (I'm not American so I'm not clear on the possible formats of a zipcode, but you can probably find regex for that part by googling it).

From our expression the part within the brackets can be extracted as a group;

```
[\da-zA-Z]{5}-[\da-zA-Z]{4}
```

As we only have one grouping, this would usually be referred to as group 0.

So using the first expression on your sample;

```
<zipcode>12345-1234</zipcode>
```

and returning group 0, would give you;

```
12345-1234
```

I'm not familiar with vbscript, so I can't answer it myself, but this answer appears to explain how to extract sub matches in vbscript;
[Regular Expression - How to find a match within a match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951872/regular-expression-how-to-find-a-match-within-a-match)

If you want to test your regexes, you should use a testing tool such as RegexPal, it highlights what is being matched in realtime so you can test parts of your expression to see whats not working.
http://regexpal.com/
Another good source of information is regex reference, this page holds alot of reference information for the basic regex functions.
[enter link description here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html)

Comment: Thank you for at least something, and I do kinda understand what you are saying... I did not know it was going to be this hard to accomplish.  There are multiple ways this zipcode can be in the text.  It could have a hyphen (5digits)-(4digits), it could not have a hyphen (12345) or (123456789) All numbers.  If there are any letters I would like it to count.  Could I not put in (\-)  for an optional hyphen?

Comment: You would use [ -]? for an optional hyphen, space or no character.
The [] create a character class of allowed characters.
The ? makes it optional.

Comment: So again I very much appreciate the help, and this is totally over my head at the moment (I am trying), but... is it safe to say, there is no simple way to just allow ANYTHING between the tags EXCEPT [a-zA-Z]?

Comment: To allow anything except you use a negate in the character class so [^a-zA-Z]* (presumably repeated any number of times).

Comment: Well we are for sure getting closer but I am very confused on the current results. What I have is, "<ZipCode>([^a-zA-Z]*)</ZipCode>"  I have 2 zipcode tags in the text file.  If I use above code, it will return 2 found items when there are nothing but Numbers between the tag.  If I add a Letter to one of them, it will return 1 found item.  So you would think it is just backwards.  So I replaced it with "<ZipCode>([^0-9]*)</ZipCode>"   and this will find NOTHING no matter what is between the tags.

Comment: Update your question with your modified code, and explain what result you expect. You still haven't made clear what exactly you want to find.

Comment: I updated it to what I have currently.  I tried to explain what the code is doing the best I can.  Long story short, I would like the pattern to find ANY LETTERS (upper or lowercase) between the tags.  If it does not find any letters in between the tags, it should report 0 instances.