# regex for SQL objects

Tags: regex, vbscript

I have a text file and I want to capture word with prefix CATS...
I am not able to figure it out.
My text file sample is:-

```
CATS...NAME_VALUATION_GEO Name_Valuation
where exists ( select 
CATS...REPORT_EVAL_NAME Report_Name
where  ( REPORT_EVAL_NAME.REPORT_EVAL_REQUEST_ID = '454' and REPORT_EVAL_NAME.INTERNAL_NAME_ID = NAME_VALUATION_GEO.OUTER_NAME_ID )  ) ) NAME_Valuation_GEO
) NAME_Valuation_GEO,
CATS...NAME_VAL_BIST_LD_PNG T2
```

It should result out :-

```
NAME_VALUATION_GEO
NAME_VAL_BIST_LD_PNG
REPORT_EVAL_NAME
```

**Edit**

I have come up with `/CATS\.\.\.(\w+)/g`
but it returns :-

```
CATS...NAME_VALUATION_GEO
CATS...NAME_VAL_BIST_LD_PNG
CATS...REPORT_EVAL_NAME
```

Any help returning

```
NAME_VALUATION_GEO
NAME_VAL_BIST_LD_PNG
REPORT_EVAL_NAME
```

I am using vb-script if that matters.

Comment: reading regex manual not able to grasp in hurry... :-)

Comment: `CATS...\.(\[^]+\])`

Comment: `CATS\.\.\.(\w+)` I think this one is correct gives me `CATS...REPORT_EVAL_NAME`

Comment: you wrote "I want to capture word with prefix CATS", this is still up-to-date?

Comment: you need to print out what you captured in the capturing group, i.e. the `$1`

Comment: You have written a working regex, just access the `.SubMatches(0)`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951872/regular-expression-how-to-find-a-match-within-a-match
access capturing group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `"CATS\.\.\.([^]]+\s)"`

I am sure it will return as per your requirement i.e.

```
NAME_VALUATION_GEO
NAME_VAL_BIST_LD_PNG
REPORT_EVAL_NAME
```

**Edit**

```
CATS\.\.\.(\w+)
```

This new expression is correct and accurate to most of scenarios where first fails.

Answer (score 1):

As I understood you need a regex to capture the first word after `CATS...`?
This regex will just do it.

`/^CATS\.\.\.(\w+)/$1/`

1. `^CATS`: match only if String begins with `CATS`
2. `\.\.\.` : followed by three dots, they need to be escaped
3. `(\w+)`: capture any word character, at least one
4. `/$1/`: the result of the capture group is stored in `$1`

Comment: not as per expected due to CATS is not always start of line

Comment: I have updated my question Please suggest