# How to search for integer in a string

Tags: vbscript, automated-tests

I'm writing scripts for automated testing and I am able to grab an objects value let's say a web element label with the value: "Job # 12345" and I'm storing that into a variable called `jobID`.

I want to be able to iterate through that string, and just grab "12345" 
Put that in some variable named let's say `newJobID`, and then have that variable inputted into a data-table.

I know how to do everything else besides iterating through that darn string and only grabbing the integers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951872/regular-expression-how-to-find-a-match-within-a-match

Answer (score 3):

Use a [regular expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wzad2b2(v=vs.84).aspx) searching for a string of digits (\d+):

```
>> Set r = New RegExp
>> r.Pattern = "\d+"
>> s = "Job # 12345"
>> sId = r.Execute(s)(0).Value
>> WScript.Echo sId
>>
12345
```

What you shouldn't do (and why):

```
>> sJobid = "Job # 12345"
>> IJobid = split( sJobid,"#")(1)
>> WScript.Echo "|" & IJobid & "|", TypeName(IJobid)
>>
| 12345| String
```

(leading blank, type prefix fraud)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it and it threw me an error, I was probably not using it right but I found another solution. I will be using the mid function instead.

Answer (score 0):

please try below code :

```
sJobid = "Job # 12345"
IJobid = split( sJobid,"#")(1)
```

IJobid is your expected result.

Please let me know if I answered your question.